# Classify the Curves in the plane

Tags: differential-geometry

Classify all the curves $c: I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ that have a curvature $\kappa=K$ with $K$ constant, for $K>0,K=0,K<0.$

Hello, if $K=0$ then necessarily the curve is a line. Because, if $c$ is parametrized for arc length, we have that $\|c''(t)\|=0\iff c''(t)=0\iff c'(t)=K\iff c(t)=Kt+c.$ Thus, $c$ is a line when $K=0.$ However, the other cases I don't understand how analize. Help me please?

Comment: Curvature depends on the _second_ derivative; you may want to re-consider your analysis of the $K = 0$ case. ;)

Comment: Thanks, now edit the message.

Comment: It is intuitive that a curve of constant curvature is a circle !

Comment: @Yves Daoust Because? :o

Comment: Because a circle has constant curvature. And because if you drive your car without touching the wheel, you... circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is convenient to use complex numbers to describe the plane that the curve is in.  Then we have the equation $\frac{d}{dt}n(t)=\kappa v(t)$ where $v$ is the tangent vector and $n$ is the normal vector.  But $n(t)=-iv(t)$ (up to sign) so the equation becomes $\frac{dv}{dt}=i\kappa v(t)$ so that $v(t)=e^{i\kappa t}$. Integrating, we obtain that the curve is necessarily $\frac{1}{\kappa} e^{i\kappa t} +C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary complex constant. Geometrically speaking, we obtain a circle of radius $1/|\kappa|$ centered at an arbitrary point of the plane.

Comment: Thanks, but I looking for a solution without complex numbers :(. In other words, any more intuitive :). It's my first course of Differential Geometry. The case $\kappa=0$ I have it clear, is an circle, but the other cases?